# Metric inducing a topology

Tags: general-topology

Can someone intuitively explain what it means for a metric to induce a topology? This may seem really apparent, but I want to make sure that I am thinking of it correctly.

Comment: Why don't you say what you think it means? That will help respondents to pitch their answers appropriately.

Comment: Maybe I won't become too much popular saying this, but I think this "intuition" thing is overrated, isn't it? Particularly in this case, when you ask about an interpretation of a simpler concept (a metric) in terms of a more abstract one (a topology). In fact I would go the other way around: once you are familiar with the open sets (whic are the basic elements of a topology) of a metric space ($\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^2$, to begin with), then you can see that the axioms defining a topology are very natural properties of open sets of metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Given a metric space $(X,d)$ we can define a topology on $X$ by declaring $U\subseteq X$ open iff for all $x\in U$ there exists $r>0$ such that $d(x,y)<r$ implies $y\in U$. It is readily verified that by the metric axioms this is indeed a topology. Moreover, this is really the correct hing to do insofar as e.g. a sequence converges in the sense defined by the metric iff it converges in the sense o fthis topology.

Answer (score 0):

For any metric space $(X,d)$, you can define open sets in terms of the metric. Combined with the theorem which says arbitrary unions and finite intersections of open sets are again open sets, these open sets then fulfil the definition of a topology. Hence, a metric "induces" a topology by specifying what sets are open for you (i.e., precisely the topology).

Answer (score 0):

Using the metric we can define open balls, then define the topology to be the one generated by  all open balls (as basis).